# Discord.py ban all members

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make code that bans all members in a server. This is for educational reasons, do not plan on doing it in a real server. My current code is:

```
@client.command()
async def d(ctx):
    for member in list(ctx.guild.members):
      try:
        await member.ban(reason="pooooop", delete_message_days=7)
        print(f"Banned {member.display_name}!")
        print("Banning is complete!")
      except Exception:
        pass
```

The code does not have any errors but is not reacting to the command.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def massban(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await user.ban()
        except:
            pass
```

you can loop through all the members and ban them

you're code should work anyways

Docs [Ban](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=ban#discord.Guild.ban)

Comment: I'm sorry but the code does not have any errors but is not responding.

Comment: does the bot have permission to ban? to check this try this
`except Exception as e:` and then replace pass with `print(e)`

Comment: Why would you write code with `except: pass` (instead of `except Exception:`), and print exceptions instead of ignoring them in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this but instead of banning, I just printing the name just to test it but it only prints one name

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def ban(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        print(member)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for member in guild.ban:
     try:
       await member.ban(ctx.guild.members)
     except Exception:
       pass
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy I made some for this

With Requests:

```
@client.command()
async def banall(ctx):
    for member in list(ctx.guild.members):
      id = ctx.guild.id
      userid = member.id
      r = requests.put('https://discord.com/guilds/{id}/bans/{userid}', headers={    'Authorization': 'put bot token here'    })
      if r.status_code != 200:
       await ctx.send(f'Banned {userid}')
      elif r.status_code != 429:
       await ctx.send(f'Could not ban {userid}\nReason: Status Code 429 Rate limited')
```

Without Requests:

```
@client.command()
async def banall(ctx):
    for member in list(ctx.guild.members):
      try:
        await member.ban(reason='banall')
      except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Log : "+str(client.user))

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.ban()
        except:
            pass

client.run("token")
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the answer.